# adding spaces between variables

Tags: php

I am doing a project for class, and I need to simply put a space between the city state country and zip variables. Please help! Thank you!

The code looks like this:

```
echo "<p>";
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['city']; 
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['state']; 
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['country']; 
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['zip']; 
echo "</p><p>";
echo $weather['current_observation']['observation_time_rfc822'];
echo "</p><p>";
echo $weather['current_observation']['weather'];
echo "</p><p>";
echo $weather['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
echo "</p><p>";
echo $weather['current_observation']['wind_string'];
echo "</p>";
```

Comment: You don't appear to have even tried to add a space...

Comment: @FelixKling: pew pew pew

Comment: I don't want to make a line break, just a space between them on the same line. I'm not sure how to do just a space.

Comment: @EricaHorvatin: Have you tried just echoing a space?  `echo " ";`?

Comment: @FelixKling: Our "edit wars" seem to have community wiki-ed the question, oops.

Comment: I am doing a project for class, and I need to simply by a new house... Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

echo `echo '&nbsp';` after any echo line you want to add a space.

Or as stated in commments:

> *"There's no need for a non-breaking space. A regular `echo " ";` will be fine. – ceejayoz May 9 '12 at 16:01"*

Comment: There's no need for a non-breaking space. A regular `echo " ";` will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['city']; 
echo ' ';
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['state'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add on to the end of a string with `.`

So `"foo" . "bar"` returns `"foobar"`

I would write

```
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['city'] . ' '; 
echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['state'] . ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add spaces this way

`echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['city'] . " ";`

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest:

```
echo " ";
```

If that's not doing the trick, you've left important details out of your question.

Answer (score -1):

For normal space do.

```
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['city'] . " ";
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['state'] . " ";
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['country'] . " ";
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['zip'] . " ";
```

or for HTML spacing do.

```
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['city'] . "&nbsp;";
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['state'] . "&nbsp;";
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['country'] . "&nbsp;";
 echo $weather['current_observation']['display_location']['zip'] . "&nbsp;";
```

Comment: "HTML spacing" is somewhat misleading. Both are HTML spacing.

Comment: @Rocket I edited my comment.. I guess now it should not amount for the negative rating :D